# How to make the user interface on Android?

Tags: user-interface, photoshop

I am making an application with android studio that would communicate with a raspberry pi and do commands. One example is that if I push X on the application, the LED lights will turn off, and if I press it again then it will turn on.

I would like to make a GUI for this. I somewhat know how to use android studio, I just can't find any tutorials now how to do this. Do I make the interface in photoshop and the assign areas that you tap on the image and an action would happen?

I'm looking into making some grayed out buttons, and once a event = 1 (true) then it would go un-gray (maybe to a blue-ish button) and green if you press it again and turn it on. This will be controlled by facial recognition but that doesn't matter for now.

Should I make it in photoshop and then make areas for them to tap or how would I go about making this GUI in android studio for a samsung galaxy s3?

Answer (score 0):

@Nick, you can definitely create the UI in PS and take it to Android studio for programming, but given the simple interface that you are describing, PS might be an overkill. Have you tried using [http://pencil.evolus.vn/], that provides barebones interface for creating simple UI.